# Java using overriden methods

Tags: java

I am a noob and I need some help.

So I have this abstract class with a private variable. I also have a method named getThing() to return that.

I have a class that extends that abstract class, and it too has a private variable and a method that overrides the original to get the value from the abstract class.

Well the only way to be able to access both values is by creating a second method in the subclass called getSuperThing, and using the super in that. Well I was just wondering out of curiosity if there was some easier way to do that and be able to access the abstract classes method by doing something like objectNae.super.getThing().

Thanks ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The variable is `private` and so can only be referenced by the containing (abstract) class.  As you have stated, from a subclass, you can invoke the superclass method (rather than the overridden one).

If you want to make the variable accessible from the subclass directly (without requiring the accessor method), make it `protected` instead.  Here is the documentation on [Controlling Access to Members of a Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html).

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, then you just shouldn't override the abstract class' method in the concrete subclass. No need to, unless you need the subclass to return a different value than that returned by the abstract class (and that would suggest poor design).

Rather, the abstract class' method will be accessible as a method of the subclass.

So, if you have:

```
public abstract class AbstractClass {
  private int value = 3;

  public int getValue() {
   return value;
  }
}

public class ConcreteClass extends AbstractClass {
}
```

then you should be able to do:

```
new ConcreteClass().getValue()
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you have other ways than calling super.getThing() in the subclass's getThing() or getSuperThing() method. Abstract class must be subclassed before being used.